# Spark: Create dataframe from arrays in a column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe (using Scala) with a column `arrays` that contains `Array[Array[Int]]`, i.e.

```
var data = Seq(
  ((1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)),
  ((1, 5, 7), (3, 4, 5), (6, 3, 0)),
  ...
).toDF("arrays")
```

I want to create a new dataframe in which each row contains one `Array[Int]` and there should be no repetitions. For example, the dataframe above would become:

```
+-----------+
|   array   |
+-----------+
| (1, 2, 3) |
| (3, 4, 5) |
| (6, 7, 8) |
| (1, 5, 7) |
| (6, 3, 0) |
+-----------+
```

where `(3, 4, 5)` appears only once.

Comment: Have you tried something like `data.withColumn("arrays", F.explode("arrays")).distinct` ? Here `F` is an alias for the `spark.sql.functions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`df.withColumn("array", explode(df.array)).dropDuplicates()`

Comment: No, I do not want it to appear twice